# How to display foreach loop result again in multiple pages

Tags: php, foreach

How can I display the upload image files again in multiple pages? For now, they preview correctly, also uploaded and displayed in 2nd page correctly. (I want the same images that uploaded to display again and in few more pages until the last page then I can submit into the MySQL table.)

```html
====== Page-1 ===========
Multiple images upload  + preview

<form action="PAGE-2"> 
<div id="image_preview"></div>

<input type="file" id="images" name="images[]" onchange="preview_images();" multiple>
<input type="submit">
</for>

====== PAGE-2 ===
Processing + Upload to /upload/ folder + display them in IMG tag



<?php
if(isset($_POST['wrap']))
{
 $images_array=array();
 foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val)
 {
     $uploadfile=$_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key];
 $folder="upload/";
 $target_file = $folder.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "$folder".$_FILES["images"]["name"][$key]))
  {
  $images_array[] = $target_file;
   }
  }
}

if(!empty($images_array))
{ 
  foreach($images_array as $src )
 { 
?>

<img src="<?php echo $src;?>"><br>

<!-- All uploaded images display correctly like
 <img src=upload/mypicture.jpg><br>
<img src=upload/dog.jpg><br>
!--> 

<?php
  }
}
?>

====== PAGE-3 - Page-5 =====

 - How to display those uploaded images again in few more pages?
```

Comment: Before saving , i think you can set a Session where you take the reference for the uploaded image.

Comment: Do you have an example code how to put those in SESSON?

Comment: Session works like an array, so you have to declare it and then you can use it. You will find all the documentation in [docs php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try to read through it.